# How would altering existential instantiation in the following way change mathematics?

Tags: logic, reference-request, axioms, foundations, alternative-set-theories

What mathematics do you think could be developed if existential instantiation was only allowed from sets and if the predicate is true for only finite/countable many elements in the given set?

Any reference is appreciated as well!

EDIT:
To be specific, the altered rule would look like this:
∃xP(x)⟹P(a)  where P is a predicate such that P=x∈A∧... and P only holds for finite/countable elements in A. Intiutively, I think, this would mean that an element with a given property of a set can only be chosen if there are a finite/countable elements with that property.

Comment: Not clear... [Existential instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_instantiation) is a rule of inference; it says nothing about the "cardinality" of the universe.

Comment: Thanks, I edited accordingly

Comment: What do you mean by "only allowed from sets"?

Comment: $\exists xP\left({x}\right)\implies P\left({\mathbf {a} }\right)$ where $P$ is a predicate such that $P=x\in A \land ...$ and $P$ only holds for finite/countable elements in $A$. Intiutively, I think, this would mean that an element with a given property of a set can only be chosen if there are a finite/countable elements with that property.